# Connecting two sequential Keras models in sequence in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I am building a Variational Autoencoder and trying to connect two sequential models in sequence but the summary doesn't reflect the end model summary like I expect too. It seems that only the encoder is connected and the output of the decoder not all the decoder layers.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as tfk
from keras import layers as tfkl
import numpy as np
import keras_tuner as kt
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow_probability import layers as tfpl
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd

def encoder_builder(hp, input_shape, latent_dim):

  prior = tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal(loc=tf.zeros(latent_dim), scale=1), reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)

  enc = tfk.Sequential()
  enc.add(tfk.Input(shape=input_shape))
  enc.add(tfkl.Flatten())

  for i in range(hp.Int("enc_num_layers", 1, 3)):
    enc.add(
        tfkl.Dense(
            # Tune number of units separately.
            units=hp.Int(f"enc_units_{i}", min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32),
            activation=hp.Choice(f"enc_activation_{i}", ["relu", "tanh"]),
        )
    )

    enc.add(
        tfkl.Dense(tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL.params_size(latent_dim), activation=None)
    )

    enc.add(
      tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL(
          latent_dim,
          activity_regularizer=tfpl.KLDivergenceRegularizer(prior))
    )

    return enc

def decoder_builder(hp, input_shape, latent_dim):
    dec = tfk.Sequential()
    dec.add(tfk.Input(shape=latent_dim))
    for i in range(hp.Int("dec_num_layers", 2, 4)):
      dec.add(
          tfkl.Dense(
              # Tune number of units separately.
              units=hp.Int(f"dec_units_{i}", min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32),
              activation=hp.Choice(f"dec_activation_{i}", ["relu", "tanh"]),
          )
      )

    dec.add(tfkl.Dense(784, activation='relu'))
    dec.add(tfkl.Reshape((28, 28)))

    return dec

def model_builder(hp):
  encoder = encoder_builder(hp, (28, 28), 2)
  decoder = decoder_builder(hp, (28, 28), 2)

  encoder.summary()
  decoder.summary()

  vae = tfk.Model(inputs=encoder.inputs,
                outputs=decoder(encoder.outputs[0]))
  vae.summary()
```

---

Encoder Summary:

flatten_49 (Flatten)        (None, 784)               0

dense_190 (Dense)           (None, 32)                25120

dense_191 (Dense)           (None, 5)                 165

multivariate_normal_tri_l_  ((None, 2),               0
45 (MultivariateNormalTriL   (None, 2))
)

---

Decoder Summary:

dense_192 (Dense)           (None, 32)                96

dense_193 (Dense)           (None, 32)                1056

dense_194 (Dense)           (None, 784)               25872

reshape_29 (Reshape)        (None, 28, 28)            0

---

VAE SUMMARY:

input_65 (InputLayer)       [(None, 28, 28)]          0

flatten_49 (Flatten)        (None, 784)               0

dense_190 (Dense)           (None, 32)                25120

dense_191 (Dense)           (None, 5)                 165

multivariate_normal_tri_l_  ((None, 2),               0
45 (MultivariateNormalTriL   (None, 2))
)

sequential_74 (Sequential)  (None, 28, 28)            27024

Comment: The problem lies in the way you connect the encoder and decoder in a VAE model. Replace `outputs=decoder(encoder.outputs[0])` by adding each layer of the encoder into the VAE model. Then, add the decoder to the VAE model. This will ensure the entire VAE architecture is reflected in the summary model.

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by adding each layer of the encoder to the VAE. How would I do that if the VAE model is not created

Comment: Replace `outputs=decoder(encoder.outputs[0])` by manually adding each layer of the encoder into the VAE model. This ensures the entire encoder layer becomes part of the VAE model.